# Solving linear algebra equation with python. Find the vector, whose conjugate product matrix is known

Tags: matrix, vector, linear-algebra, transpose, tensor

I have a `3X1` vector(say `a`) and it's transpose `1X3` vector. I take their outer product using numpy i.e.

`np.outer(a, a.T.conj()) = b`

we just name the product matrix as `b`. Now my question is, I know the value of `b` but don't know the value of `a`. Is it possible compute the `a` vector ?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this question would fit better on a mathematics site rather than a programming one.

In brief, the answer is: not quite. a and -a give the same outer product.

This is the extent of the ambiguity, I think.

```
if B = a*a' then
B[i,i] = a[i]*a[i] so if also
B = b*b' then
b[i] = +-a[i]
```

If at least two of the a are non zero, say a[i] and a[j], we can't choose different signs because we must have

```
a[i]*a[j] = B[i,j] = b[i]*b[j]
```

If only one a[i] is non zero then there's only one sign to choose.